# Left Join in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, left-join

```
 var query = (from pn in PriorNavPositions 
         join sa in SourceDataset.SourceInvestorAllocations  on
             new { SourceDatasetId = pn.SourceDatasetId, Iqid = pn.SubscriberFiid, ShareIndex = pn.ShareIndex } equals
             new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } 
         join ea in EfrontNavDataset.EfrontNavInvestorAllocations on
             new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } equals
             new { SourceDatasetId = ea.EfrontNavDataset.SourceDatasetId, Iqid = ea.IqId, ShareIndex = ea.ShareIndex } into pnj
         from ea in pnj.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new { sa, ea, pn }
```

I am looking for left join in this EF query to get all the records from table PriorNavPositions.

Answer (score 0):

Use group join (e.g.: `join _ in _ on _ equals _ into _`) and then call `DefaultIfEmpty` on the result of the group join:

```
from pn in PriorNavPositions
    join sa in SourceDataSet.SourceInvestorAllocations
    on new { ... } equals new { ... }
    into groupJoinResult
    from gjr in groupJoinResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/standard-query-operators/join-operations#perform-left-outer-joins